# PHP get text from Dropown List

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a dropdown list which displays the directories. If i choose one and push the Button Submit, a action will be performed. Now I need a second Button Download, which compress the files and download the zip file.
My problem is that I won't get the selected Item in PHP.
Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="myDirs" id="myDirs">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Select a folder</option>
        <?php
        foreach(glob('auswertung/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir) {
            $dir = str_replace('auswertung/', '', $dir);
            echo '<option value="'.$dir.'">'.$dir."</option>\n";
        }
        ?>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="test()" />
    <form method="POST" action=''>
    <input type="submit" value="Download Files" name="download"> 
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test(){
            var e = document.getElementById("myDirs");
            console.log(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);
            }
    </script>
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['download'])) {
            $dirs = $_GET['myDirs'];
            $files = array('auswertung/"'.$dirs.'"/Coordinates.txt', 'auswertung/"'.$dirs.'"/MagnetField.txt', 'auswertung/"'.$dirs.'"/Timestamps.txt');
            /*$zipname = 'file.zip';
            $zip = new ZipArchive;
            $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
            foreach ($files as $file) {
              $zip->addFile($file);
            }
            $zip->close();
            header('Content-Type: application/zip');
            header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
            readfile($zipname);*/
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new to PHP. I get the following error message:

> Notice: Undefined index: myDirs in C:\PATH\htdocs\folder.php on line 20

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all put the `select` to inside the `form` and Change

```
$dirs = $_GET['myDirs'];
```

to

```
$dirs = $_POST['myDirs'];
```

Because your form action is `POST`

Answer (score 1):

You select element is not inside the form.

you should use

`$dirs = $_POST['myDirs'];`  instead of 
`$dirs = $_GET['myDirs'];`

as form method is set to `POST`

Answer (score 1):

```
$dirs = $_REQUEST['myDirs'];
```

use $_REQUEST then you will get & post data

Answer (score 0):

Your select element with the name myDirs is not inside the form element. Only when the select element is inside the form element will it's data be posted with the form.